# Why do 2 mobile devices and 2 emulators give different results?

Tags: android, mobile

I tested my website presentation on mobiready and cybercrab emulators, as well as on 2 different mobiles (both run Android Lollipop).  I'm getting 3 different results: one of the mobiles and mobiready are showing (different) significant errors, while cybercrab and the other mobile agree and display as expected.

I'm left confused as to what people are seeing on their mobiles. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Emulators are compared with ROOTED phones ,as we all know rooted phones cannot be trusted since the OS registry is all messed up coming to the Devices of different manufacture it is not uncommon to get different results ,As a developer i have faced the problem my self in Live application i simply had to work around